# Using weak references to implement composition

Tags: python, composition

Weak references can be used  to pass around a composite object attribute? Say you have a class with the attribute A. Any part of your code can now fetch a reference to A, but if the class instance that is composed of A is deleted A must be deleted but if it's referenced elsewhere it won't. It's ok to implement that kind of behavior with weak references in the way that the only strong reference to A is owned by the composed object?

```
class B:
 def __init__(self):
   self.A = SomeClass()
```

Comment: Why *must* the component be deleted if A is deleted?

Comment: If the component is deleted A must be deleted.

Comment: That's the opposite of what the question appears to say. In any case, that won't happen: The `B` instance has a reference to the `SomeClass` object, so it keeps it alive.

Answer (score 1):

Weak references are used to *avoid* keeping instances around, not to ensure that an object is deleted when their referant is.

The `SomeClass()` instance will *only* be deleted from memory when all *strong* references to it are deleted (with any reference that is not a weak reference being a strong reference instead).

If the `B().A` attribute is the *only* reference to an instance of `SomeClass()`, then that instance will be deleted when the `B().A` reference is rebound to something else or cleared (if `B()` is deleted the `B().A` attribute would automatically be cleared), as the reference count to `SomeClass()` drops to 0.

In other words, if `B().A` were to be a weak reference to `SomeClass()`, and there were no *other* references to `SomeClass()`, dereferencing `B().A` would return `None` instead, as the `SomeClass()` would already be deleted.

Using weak references *outside* of `B().A` could, however, be a way to ensure that `B().A` were to be the *only* strong reference to that `SomeClass()` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Python delete marks the object for *potential* deletion and decrements the reference counter - final deletion only occurs once the reference counter reaches zero.

Comment: Only in CPython. This is an implementation feature, not a requirement of the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your use case is something like this:

```
b = B()

def reset_b():
    global b
    b = B() # drops the reference to b, so it (and b.A) should be garbage collected

def get_a():
    return b.A
```

And your concern is that saved `A` references returned from `get_a` remain valid after `b` has been reset. If that's right, then weak references could be a way to fix it:

```
import weakref

def get_a():
    return weakref.proxy(b.A)
```

The `proxy` object will raise exceptions for most operations if it is used after the `b.A` object it was referring to has been deleted.

I'm not sure that this is a good design though. A better solution is probably to simply document that the results of `get_a` shouldn't be cached long term. Instead it should be called again whenever a new reference is needed. This won't require any complicated referencing schemes or exception handling, and it is much easier to think about and test.